# GStreamer pipeline + OpenCV VideoCapture.read() returns None

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to get GStreamer + OpenCV RTSP video capture using the following:

```py
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("""rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.100.60:554/stream1 latency=0 ! queue ! rtph264depay
        ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink""", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)        
while True:
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    print(frame)
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

However, the frame read by `vcap` is `None`:

```
(<unknown>:79564): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:27:54.660: invalid cast from 'GstQueue' to 'GstBin'

(<unknown>:79564): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:27:54.660: gst_bin_iterate_elements: assertion 'GST_IS_BIN (bin)' failed

(<unknown>:79564): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:27:54.660: gst_iterator_next: assertion 'it != NULL' failed

(<unknown>:79564): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:27:54.660: gst_iterator_free: assertion 'it != NULL' failed
[ WARN:0@0.020] global /tmp/opencv-20220409-60041-xvxfur/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1226) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.020] global /tmp/opencv-20220409-60041-xvxfur/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Data/Projects/rtmp_test/src/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    read(1)
  File "/Volumes/Data/Projects/rtmp_test/src/test.py", line 18, in read
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /tmp/opencv-20220409-60041-xvxfur/opencv-4.5.5/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1000: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

The stream can be played in VLC perfectly fine and `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.100.60:554/stream1 latency=0 ! queue ! rtph264depay! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink` gives regular output. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

UPDATE: I've noticed that this problem occurs only on OSX. It  works fine on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try specifying caps as video format BGR (or GRAY8 for monochrome) before appsink as this would be the default format expected by most cases from OpenCV (also maybe simplifying quoting) such as:

```
gst_pipeline='rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.100.60:554/stream1 latency=0 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Also note that printing each frame in terminal in the loop may prevent from running at expected framerate depending on your use case and platform.

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid. I notice the problem occurs only on OSX. It works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ahh.. I don't have experience with OSX, sorry. I just know that some properties are not managed the same way depending on the platform, such as udpsink and udpsrc (the latter would be used by rtspsrc) requiring property `address` to be set explictly. First try using gst-launch-1.0 -v for a receiving pipeline and only move to opencv when this works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this in VSCode by any chance?

I had the same `GStreamer warning`, turns out VSCode didn't have permissions for camera access on OSX. Ran same code on PyCharm instead and the "App123 would like to access your camera" OSX system dialog popped up, once I clicked `ok`, the camera streams properly. Could explain why it works fine on Ubuntu but not OSX.

VSCode issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95062